Can a marriage condition be broken if it leads to haram or neglecting responsibility?
Suppose a man had marriage with a woman. It was stipulated in the nikkah contract that she would continue working after marriage.
Now some problems arise,
A) She does not wear hijab due to one or the other reason.
B) She works in a mixed working place (like say coed school, company with no segregation in a non Muslim country,etc).
C) She many times is not able to fulfill her husband's rights.
D) After 3 years, she has a child. But her working out may harm the child's development.
Can the husband in these case ask her to withdraw from work?
Note: The first 2 cases are something haram, 3rd case is inability to fulfil something obligatory while doing something optional and the 4th one is about her responsibility.
Please answer with valid sources.
